# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que mi programa termine cuando se presiona la tecla cero "0" y de el promedio de las edades, la suma y también el número de alumnos?

Tags: c

tengo una pregunta, mi programa ya funciona, y ya lo había puesto anteriormente, pero ahora me encuentro en un dilema, ya que me piden que este programa debe terminar su proceso cuando se pulse la tecla cero "0" y muestre automáticamente la suma de las edades, su promedio y el número de alumnos que hay. Me quede estancado y no se si me pueden ayudar con esto.

```
/*Elabora un programa en lenguaje C para calcular el promedio de la edad de los alumnos del grupo 8292.
 El programa deberá solicitar la edad de cada alumno. La edad válida estará entre 18 y 40 años.
 El programa termina de pedir edades cuando la edad es 0 y debe mostrar la suma de las edades, el número de alumnos y el promedio.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void)
{
    int i, n, exit;
    float edad, promedio;
    promedio = 0;
    printf ("Ingrese el numero de estudiantes del grupo 8292: ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    getchar ();
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        do
        {
            printf ("Estudiante %d\n", i);
            printf ("Ingrese la edad del estudiante: ");
            scanf ("%f", &edad);
            exit = (edad < 18 || edad > 40);
            if(exit) //Esto es equivalente a if(exit != 0)
                printf("\nError: La edad debe estar en el rango de 18 a 40 anios!\n");
        }while(exit);//Equivalente a exit != 0
        getchar ();
        promedio=promedio+edad;
        putchar('\n');
    }
    if (n == 0)
        edad = 0;
    else
        promedio=promedio/n;
    printf ("El promedio de edades del grupo 8292 es: %f\n", promedio);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > El programa termina de pedir edades cuando la edad es 0

Simplemente usemos un bucle `do-while` en la cual haga iteraciones hasta que la edad sea `0`. Esto significa que debemos permitir al usuario que pueda ingresar una edad nula para poder salir del programa.

Entonces modificaremos esta condición:

```c
exit = (edad < 18 || edad > 40);
```

Y la cambiaremos a:

```c
exit = ((edad < 18 || edad > 40) && (edad != 0));
```

Con esta restricción el usuario solo podrá ingresar edades que estén en el rango de `18` a `40` y que sean diferentes a `0`, de este modo, cuando el usuario ingrese un `0`, no lo tomará como **inválido** y esto hace que el bucle `do-while` anidado se rompa.

Otro requerimiento sería que solo contaremos los alumnos cuando la edad sea diferente a `0`.

El código con las modificaciones quedaría así:

```c
int main (void)
{
    //Debemos inicializar la variable n
    int i = 0, n = 0, exit;
    float edad, promedio;
    promedio = 0;
    getchar ();
    do
    {
        i++;
        do
        {
            printf ("Estudiante %d\n", i);
            printf ("Ingrese la edad del estudiante: ");
            scanf("%f", &edad);
            exit = ((edad < 18 || edad > 40) && (edad != 0));
            if(exit) //Esto es equivalente a if(exit != 0)
                printf("\nError: La edad debe estar en el rango de 18 a 40 anios!\n");
        }while(exit);//Equivalente a exit != 0
        getchar ();
        promedio=promedio+edad;
        if(edad != 0)
            n++;
        putchar('\n');
    }while(edad != 0);
    printf("La suma de las edades fue: %f\n", promedio);
    promedio=promedio/n;
    printf ("El promedio de edades del grupo 8292 es: %f\n", promedio);
    printf("Numeros de alumnos: %d\n", n);
    system ("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias MrDave1999, se lo agradezco mucho.